# Why does awk print the entire line instead of the first field?

Tags: shell, awk

I'm trying to learn to use `awk` but it's not behaving how I expect. Here's my trouble:

```
$ echo "Hello brave new world" | awk "{print $1}"
Hello brave new world
```

I expected to see "Hello", as this is the first field. Why don't the spaces count as field delimiters?

Comment: So, you have learned more about shell programming than Awk programming; the answers so far are spot on.  Always use single quotes around scripts - unless there are extremely cogent reasons to do otherwise.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's because Bash is interpreting `$1` as referring to the first shell argument, so it replaces it with its value. Since, in your case, that parameter is unset, `$1` just gets replaced with the empty string; so your AWK program is actually just `{print }`, which prints the whole line.

To prevent Bash from doing this, wrap your AWK program in single-quotes instead of double-quotes:

```
echo "Hello brave new world" | awk '{print $1}'
```

or

```
echo 'Hello brave new world' | awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 7):

```
 echo "Hello brave new world" | awk '{print $1}'
```

Use single quotes around the awk program, otherwise $1 gets translated as the shell variable $1

Answer (score 2):

To print the entire line, run this shell-command:

```
echo "Hi, this is my first answer on stackoverflow" | awk '{ print $0 }'
```

output:

```
Hi, this is my first answer on stackoverflow
```

Comment: Hi @Azedin - welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your answer seems like it is very similar to the other 2 answers (including the accepted one from 9 years ago!!).  If you think you have something new to add to the solutions please add it to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $0 for full line.

```
$ cat <<EOF | head -1 | sed "s/\t/\n/g" | awk 'BEGIN { cont=0} { print ++cont " " $0}'
> First Name    His/Her Phone   Electronic mail address Acquaintance or Friend
Amelia  555-5553        amelia.zodiacusque@gmail.com    F
Anthony 555-3412        anthony.asserturo@hotmail.com   A
Becky   555-7685        becky.algebrarum@gmail.com      A
EOF
1 First Name
2 His/Her Phone
3 Electronic mail address
4 Acquaintance or Friend
```

Data comes from https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Sample-Data-Files
but here is tab separated.

See also https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Very-Simple